# Best way to programmatically manipulate an hand-drawn line

Tags: html, canvas, graphics, bitmap, 2d

**Please notice that I have no background on mathematics or computer graphics.**

I would like to know the best way to programmaticaly manipulate an hand-drawn line, if it is even possible.

The draw action must be done in a html page. (may be irrelevant)

methods I tough off:

1. Draw a line into a canvas (hand-drawn line with up and downs) -> convert to bitmap -> somewhow intepret line on bitmap and manipulate its form (is this possible?)
2. Instead of interpret from bitmap, at the drawing moment have a kind of button to toggle capture on/off and after capture, generate some kind of mathematical function wich I am able to manipulate and from it generate the new bitmap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.

It's not difficult, but there are lots of small coding aspects to learn.

If you’re in “drawing” mode, you would collect mousepoints that the user clicks and make a line from all those points.

If you’re in “editing” mode, you would let the user drag one of those collected points to a new coordinate and make a line from all the edited points.

Here’s starting code for you to look and learn from plus a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/J5PrN/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    #canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.lineJoin = "round";
    ctx.lineWidth=3;

    var canvasOffset=$("#canvas").offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;
    var isDown=false;
    var startX;
    var startY;

    var points=[];
    var selected=-1;
    var mode="draw";

    function draw(){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(points[0].x,points[0].y);
        for(var i=1;i<points.length;i++){
            ctx.lineTo(points[i].x,points[i].y);
        }
        ctx.stroke();
        if(mode=="edit"){
            for(var i=0;i<points.length;i++){
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(points[i].x,points[i].y,10,0,Math.PI*2);
                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.fill();
            }
        }
    }

    function handleMouseDown(e){
      startX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      startY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      if(mode=="draw"){
          points.push({x:startX,y:startY});
          draw();
      }else if(mode=="edit"){
          for(var i=0;i<points.length;i++){
              var pt=points[i];
              var dx=startX-pt.x;
              var dy=startY-pt.y;
              if(dx*dx+dy*dy<100){
                  selected=i;
                  return;
              }
          }
      }

    }

    function handleMouseUp(e){
        selected=-1;
    }

    function handleMouseOut(e){
        selected=-1;
    }

    function handleMouseMove(e){
      if(selected<0){return;}

      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // Put your mousemove stuff here
      if(selected<0){return;}
      var dx=mouseX-startX;
      var dy=mouseY-startY;
      startX=mouseX;
      startY=mouseY;
      var pt=points[selected];
      points[selected]={x:pt.x+dx,y:pt.y+dy};
      draw();
    }

    $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
    $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseOut(e);});

    $("#draw").click(function(){ 
        mode="draw"; 
        draw(); 
        $instructions.text("Click points to draw a line");
    });
    $("#edit").click(function(){ 
        mode="edit"; 
        draw(); 
        $instructions.text("Drag points to move the line");
    });
    $instructions=$("#instructions");


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <button id="draw">Add to Line</button>
    <button id="edit">Change Line</button><br>
    <p id="instructions">Click points to draw a line</p>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to HTML, but in most applications I have seen [(such as this one)](http://nonlinearideas.com/tools-you-build-part-i-observer/), hand drawn lines are broken up into small straight segments.  This is because the sensing system (touch or mouse) gives your application a (somewhat) continuous stream of points; it does not give the actual line.  The individual segments are then used to do whatever the goal of the application is.

In the case of line drawing, as the line is drawn, the application takes the points and smooths them (cubic spline, least squares polynomial fit, b-spline, etc.) then draws the smoothed lines onto the screen in the color and style (pen, pencil, chalk, etc.).  This gives the user immediate feedback about where their hand is moving, etc.

In the case of gestural control, some overlay line may be drawn to give the user feedback, but the segments are processed differently to determine the gesture (this can be very complex).

Having the lines cached as a series of gestures gives you options for undo/redo.  You can also store the drawing as a series of gestures instead of a fixed bitmap.

Was this helpful?